# How do you add devices to a provisioning profile in Apple's updated developer portal?

Tags: ios

I was always able to do this by checking the devices i wanted to add, but I can't find that option with the interface update.

I just edited an old profile (which had 14 devices), so that i can add a new tester, but now it tells me that it has no devices registered for it.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple just redesigned iOS Dev Center this weekend with certain stupid rules. Now you cannot edit your ad-hoc distribution provisioning profile. To add any device you will have to create new Provisioning profile and add all the devices. Once a device is added, you can just edit its name only.